# Is this a convex matrix function?

Tags: matrices, functions, convex-analysis

Suppose $Q=qq^T$ with $q\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Consider the function
$$V(Q) = \|Q-Q_d\|_F^2\,\bigg[-\log \bigg(-\frac{\langle M, Q \rangle}{2} \bigg) \bigg]$$

1. $\|\cdot\|_F$: frobenius norm for matrix
2. $M, Q_d\in \mathcal{S}^{n\times n}$, symmetric
3. $Q_d = q_dq_d^T$.
4. $\langle M, Q\rangle = \text{tr}(MQ)$
5. $Q\in \mathcal{C}=\{Q: 0 \leq -\frac{\langle M, Q \rangle}{2}\leq1\}$

Now, I use the following fact

1. $\|\cdot\|_F^2$  is a convex function
2. $-\log(\cdot)$ is convex and nonincreasing
3. $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is concave/convex
4. Composition rule of 2 and 3

So $V(Q)$ is convex.

Can I argue convexity of a matrix function through this?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that you want to evaluate your function only on rank 1 matrices, so your domain is not convex. One typically requires the domain to be convex for a function to be convex. You also may need to adjust the set $\mathcal{C}$ you consider: Currently you allow the possibility $\langle M,Q \rangle =0$ in which case you have $-\log (0)$. Also, the product of convex functions need to be convex. It doesn't seem that this is addressed by your argument.

Comment: @Eric Thanks! I think the main problem is $Q$. I will try to adjust $Q\in \mathcal{S}_+^n$ with $\text{tr}(Q) = 1$. So I will remove $Q= qq^T$. For the second one, I will remove $0$. Then the product of two convex function will be convex.

Comment: For example $x^2$ and $-\log(x)$ are both convex but their product is not. Your function looks very similar to this, so it seems unlikely to me that it will be convex.

Comment: @Eric Thanks! I will use second order method to test it.